# vector<Class> has no member "function"

Tags: c++

I have two classes (Vector3 is an irrelevant class here):

```
class Room {
  public:
    Room();

  private:
    vector<Button> roombuttons[3];
};
```

and

```
class Button {
  public:
    Button();
    Button(Vector3 pos);

    void SetPos(Vector3 pos);

  private:
    Vector3 pos;
}
```

If I want to define `Room()` as:

```
Room::Room() { 
  roombuttons[0].SetPos(100,100,0);
}
```

I get an error saying `class "std::vector<Button, std::allocator<Button>>" has no member "SetPos"`
Why am I not able to call the `SetPos` function of the Button class on Button instances in a vector?

I want to have a Room instance with a couple Buttons that are stored in some kind of array so that I can use them like elements of an array.

Comment: If you want fixed-size, use `std::array<Button,3> roombuttons;`. Right now you're declaring an array of three vectors. not a vector of size three.

Comment: `vector<Button> roombuttons[3];` - do you really want to create an array of vectors of buttons? You probably want `vector<Button> roombuttons(3);`

Comment: @NeilButterworth that syntax cannot be used in a class definition

Comment: `roombuttons[0]` is a `vector<Button>`, not a `Button`. It doesn't have a member function named `SetPos`.

Comment: `vector<Button> roombuttons[3];` should be `vector<Button> roombuttons = vector<Button>(3);`

Comment: @NathanOliver -- maybe. But that's guessing.

Comment: I just want a Room that has 5 Buttons and I don't want to have a unique name for every button but just an array where all buttons are stored. I'm new to OOP and it's a little confusing.

Comment: @Fl.pf. Then you need to get rid of the `[3]` on the declaration of `roombuttons`.  You want a single vector of buttons, not an array of vectors.

Comment: @NathanOliver note that `vector<Button> roombuttons = vector<Button>(3);` would only work in C++11 and later.  For earlier versions, you have to declare only `vector<Button> roombuttons;` in the class declaration, and then use `roombuttons(3)` in the constructor's member initialization list, or `roombuttons = vector<Button>(3);` in the constructor's body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are declaring `roombuttons` as an array of `vector` objects, thus `roombuttons[0]` is accessing the 1st `vector`, not the 1st `Button`.  So the error is correct, `vector` does not have a method named `SetPos()`.  You would need something more like this instead:

```
roombuttons[0][0].SetPos(100,100,0);
```

But that is not what you are really asking for.  You want an array of `Button`s, so either

- change your array to be a single `vector` instead, and then populate it in the constructor:

  ```
  class Room {
    public:
      Room();

    private:
      vector<Button> roombuttons;
  };

  Room::Room() : roombuttons(3) { 
    roombuttons[0].SetPos(100,100,0);
    ...
  }
  ```
- or, just get rid of the `vector` since you know up front how many `Button`s you want:

  ```
  class Room {
    public:
      Room();

    private:
      Button roombuttons[3];
  };

  Room::Room() { 
    roombuttons[0].SetPos(100,100,0);
    ...
  }
  ```

Comment: or `std::array<Button,3> roombuttons;`

Answer (score 0):

just do

```
vector<Button> roombuttons;
```

instead of

```
vector<Button> roombuttons[3];
```

Comment: And don't forget to add actual `Button` objects to `roombuttons` before you can then access any of them by index

Comment: There better be some objects allocated or this will invoke undefined behavior on first `operator[]` access. The OP could always just `Button roombuttons[3];` and call it good if the size is indeed fixed.

Comment: @WhozCraig Size is fixed for all Rooms, didn't know it was this easy, thank you.